# Old Borland Chess WebService help please

Tags: delphi, soap

I'm looking for a viable link to the 'old' borland chess server so i can connect my chessboard client? Also, i do have the client chessboard, the chessCGIserver and the chessbook (intelligence) - i would like to know how to setup the web server.

Note: Old WSDL (chessWebService) link was first:
http://wwwapp1.borland.com/webchess/ChessCGIServer.exe/wsdl/IBorlandChess
then :
http://www.danmarinescu.com/WebServices/ChessCGIServer.exe/wsdl/IBorlandChess

You will find this text at [Dr Bob's web site](http://www.drbob42.com/) about this borland chess soap service (given links are now dead):

> 2002/01/24 - The Chess WebService is Back!
>   The Chess WebService IBorlandChess, implemented by Borland Software Engineer 
>   Dan Marinescu, is back in the new domain www.danmarinescu.com and listed on
>   xmethods. The Chess WebService implements an extremely scalable SOAP
>   interface to a fully featured, high performance (competition level) Chess
>   Engine, which is completely stateless.
>
> The Chess WebService is currently written in Delphi 6. Soon, we will
>   have the very same WebService written in Kylix 2 & C++Builder 6 - very
>   soon!.
>
> Dr.Bob says... I've check out the source code for the client and server,
>   and played a few games with the client binary, and am (again) very impressed
>   by this amazing WebService. Well done! 2002/01/24 - The Chess WebService is
>   Back!
>
> The Chess WebService IBorlandChess, implemented by Borland
>   Software Engineer Dan Marinescu, is back in the new domain
>   www.danmarinescu.com and listed on xmethods. The Chess WebService
>   implements an extremely scalable SOAP interface to a fully featured, high
>   performance (competition level) Chess Engine, which is completely stateless.
>
> The Chess WebService is currently written in Delphi 6. Soon, we will
>   have the very same WebService written in Kylix 2 & C++Builder 6 - very
>   soon!.
>
> Dr.Bob says... I've check out the source code for the client and server,
>   and played a few games with the client binary, and am (again) very impressed
>   by this amazing WebService. Well done!

As far as i know, Dan Marinescu was the last 'owner' of the service.

I have all the sources in hand, i have ported them to Delphi 2009. I miss the information about how to setup the webservice / soap on my server. Any one can help?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a compiled ISAPI (or was it a CGI exe?), then you can install that in IIS as WebService -like any other ISAPI application. ASP.NET web space locations are usually NOT sufficient for that.

If you cannot get it working and if you supply the (updated) source then I will have a look.

Regards,
 Olaf

Comment: Hello - Server side is made of a delphi exe cgiserver, a dll and a xml file containing connection scripts (wsdl). The server has connection strings to be fixed. Something like:

defWSDL='http://localhost:8080/Chess/IBorlandChess.wsdl'
defURL='http://localhost:8080/Chess/ChessCGIServer/IBorlandChess';
defSvc='IBorlandChessservice'
defPrt='IBorlandChessPort'

Client side (the chessboard) has connection to the wsdl file, something like:

WSDLLocation='http://localhost:8080/chess/ChessCGIServer.exe/wsdl/IBorlandChess';

Comment: And yes i would appreciate your help. Tell me how i can send you the files (zip). I have an apache server on unix (that will be no good for the exe cgi & dll). I  have also a Sambar server on a PC machine (XP). Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to port that "CGI-standalone-WSDL" version to a more modern Delphi "integrated" ISAPI-based SOAP solution.
You can email the sources zipped to olaf (at) monien (dot) net

Answer (score 1):

I have the source code for the Chess web service, and migrated it to Delphi 2009 some time ago already. It's un and running on my server.

The WSDL is at:

http://www.bobswart.nl/cgi-bin/ChessISAPIServer.dll/wsdl/IDelphiChess

CGI is also available (change ISAPI to CGI, .dll to .exe).

Comment: What is the port number .. please. Thank You.